# New Dataset not Reflecting Table Display

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am able to print the updated value of dataset but the new added row did not reflecting the updated data from the table component display.

I temporarily put the event on keypress to trigger for adding new row on the table, here the simple code that I playing.

```
function createData(hardware, cost, status) {
  return { hardware, cost, status };
}

const tblData = [];

class Main extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tblData: [],
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <><><Box
        sx={{
          width: 500,
          maxWidth: '100%',
        }}
      >
        <TextField
          fullWidth
          label="Scan Here"
          id="fullWidth"
          onKeyPress={(e) => {
            if (e.key === 'Enter') {

              //*****--------------------------------------------------
              // - Here is the part where I was able to get the updated data but not reflecting on the table display
              console.log('Enter key pressed');
              tblData.push(createData('blah', 356, 'Yes'));
              console.log(tblData);
              //
              //--------------------------------------------------*****

            }
          } } />
      </Box><TableContainer component={Paper}>
          <Table sx={{ minWidth: 650, marginTop: '10px' }} aria-label="simple table">
            <TableHead>
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell>Hardware</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">Cost</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">status</TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            </TableHead>
            <TableBody>
              {tblData.map((row) => (
                <TableRow
                  key={row.name}
                  sx={{ '&:last-child td, &:last-child th': { border: 0 } }}
                >
                  <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                    {row.hardware}
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="right">{row.cost}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="right">{row.status}</TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              ))}
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
        </TableContainer></>
        
    )
  }
}

export default Main;
```

Any suggestion or comments how to refresh the updated data. TIA

Answer (score 0):

Just pushing element to the state doesn't trigger rerendering.

```
<TextField
  fullWidth
  label="Scan Here"
  id="fullWidth"
  onKeyPress={(e) => {
    console.log('Enter key pressed');
    this.setState((prev) => {
      tblData: prev.tblData.concat([createData('blah', 356, 'Yes')]) // this line is edited.
    }))
  }}
/>
```

Hope this would be helpful for you.

Comment: still the same, not reflecting on the display

Comment: @SyntaxRommel. I have edited my answer. I found the return value of `createData` is not an array but an object.

Answer (score 0):

It's working now, I just missed the `setState` to refresh the value.

```
console.log('Enter key pressed');
tblData.push(createData('blah', 356, 'Yes'));
this.setState({
        setState: tblData 
});
```